# Extract Specific Portion of strings between small brackets in python

Tags: python

I have data which start with integer number then string but in somecase special tagging along with string.Ex: 8 ((  NP  
8.1 جے
8.2 پور
    ))
For this, i am trying to access and then join into one line.

```
>filter_list = [] #empty 
>list huge_list = []   #empty list
>with open('filename.txt','r', encoding="utf8") as f: #read file 
>huge_list = f.readlines() #read line by line 
>for i in huge_list:
    >x = i[i.find("\t((\tNP\t")+1: i.find("))")]     ** #try to extract string like 8   ((  NP  <ne=NEL>
       8.1  جے      
       8.2  پور     
       ))**
       >if (x not in range(0)):
         >filter_list.append(x)

>print(filter_list) 
>Output: [''<Sentence id="null">', '0\t((\tSSF\t',  '1\tگلابی\t\t', 
 '2\tشہر\t\t', '3\tکے\t\t', '4\tنام\t\t', '5\tسے\t\t',
  '6\tمشہور\t\t', '7\t،\t\t', '8((\tNP\t<ne=NEL>', '8.1\tجے\t\t',  
  '8.2\tپور\t\t', '\t', '9\t،\t\t', '((\tNP\t<ne=NEL>','</Sentence>'
>**Desired Output:** 8((\tNP\t<ne=NEL>', '8.1\tجے\t\t', '8.2\tپور\t\t')) 


enter code here
```

Comment: Please edit your question to format your code and to quote your output. You can follow the guide on this question/answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks. I would do it for you but I'm not confident that I'm not going to inadvertently change the meaning, since your question is so un-formatted right now.

Comment: Additionally it might be helpful if you can provide an example that replicates your problem without using non-English characters. If you can, you will have isolated a separate code problem. If not it is most likely a unicode issue.

Comment: @HFBrowning i have done formatting of my code. please check now

Comment: Suppose i have english corpus.

Comment: If i have english corpus: ''<Story id="">
<Sentence id="null">
0 (( SSF 
1 the
2   place
3   which
4   is
5   popular
6   is
7   (( NP <ne=NEL>
7.1  Lahore
7.2  Karachi
     ))  ''   ** i want to extract concentrate (7,7.1,7.2) into single line.**